# Pass a method through/as a parameter - ANDROID

Tags: java, android

I have 2 classes:

TelaCadastroRestaurante (extends Activity) and Metodos (doesn't extends Activity).

On my first class i have this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9GH2.png

On my second class i have this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGox1.png

So, What do i want to? In my method caixaCerteza(), i want pass the method mandarNuvem() through/as PARAMETER 3.

---

public class TelaCadastroRestaurante extends Activity {

```
private EditText nomeRestaurante, emailRestaurante, telefoneRestaurante;
private Button buttonProximo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_cadastro_restaurante);
    incializarComponentes();
    acaoBotoes();
}

public void incializarComponentes() {
    nomeRestaurante = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNomeRestauranteTelaCadastroRestaurante);
    emailRestaurante = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmailRestauranteTelaCadastroRestaurante);
    telefoneRestaurante = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTelefoneRestauranteTelaCadastroRestaurante);
    buttonProximo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonProximoTelaCadastroRestaurante);

}

public void acaoBotoes() {
    buttonProximo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pegarValores();
            callMandarNuvem();
        }
    });
}

public void pegarValores(){
    final Restaurante rest = new Restaurante();
    rest.setNomeRest(nomeRestaurante.getText().toString());
    rest.setEmailRest(emailRestaurante.getText().toString());
    rest.setTelefoneRest(Integer.parseInt(telefoneRestaurante.getText().toString()));

}

public void callMandarNuvem(){
    Metodos.caixaCerteza(TelaCadastroRestaurante.this, 
                        "Você tem certeza que deseja cadastrar o restaurante " + nomeRestaurante.getText().toString() + "?", 
                        Metodos.mandarNuvem(TelaCadastroRestaurante.this));
}
```

}

public class Metodos {

```
private static ProgressDialog dialog;

// Metodo que mostra o Aguarde a verificação
public static void taskInProgres(boolean mostrar, Context context) {

    if (dialog == null) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "","Espere um momento...", true);
    }
    if (mostrar) {
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}

// Metodo que mostra a caixa de certeza
public static void caixaCerteza(final Context context, final String texto, final Metodos metodo) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builderaction = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builderaction.setTitle("Atenção!");
    builderaction.setMessage(texto);

    builderaction.setPositiveButton("Sim",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
    builderaction.setNegativeButton("Não",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builderaction.create();
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_stop);
    alert.show();
}


public static void mandarNuvem(final Context context){

    Metodos.taskInProgres(true, context);

        Restaurante rest = new Restaurante();

        ParseObject restauranteParse = new ParseObject("Restaurante");
        restauranteParse.put("nomeRestaurante", rest.getNomeRest());
        restauranteParse.put("emailRestaurante", rest.getEmailRest());
        restauranteParse.put("telefoneRestaurante", rest.getTelefoneRest());
        restauranteParse.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Salvo com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Metodos.taskInProgres(false, context);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Don't post your code or other text as a picture, copy and paste in into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a method, but an object containing a method. This means maybe slightly more code. Call `caixaCerteza` with something like

```
caixaCerteza(..., ..., new Callable() {
    @Override
    public void call() {
        mandarNuvem();
    }
});
```

In method `caixaCerteza(..., ..., Callable callable)`, execute the method with

```
callable.call();
```

**EDIT:**

This can even be simplified if the method `mandarNuvem` can be put in a class that implements some interface/extends a superclass (for example, `Callable`) that can then serve as a third parameter of `caixaCerteza` directly (instead of wrapping it in an anonymous `Callable` object).

Comment: Look what i just did:

http://i.imgur.com/5fNB2o7.png AND

http://i.imgur.com/jLjr1lG.png

Then, everytime i want pass a different method in caixaCerteza(), i will create a new Runnable with the method i want, inside this Runnable.... Did i do it right?

Comment: Yes, you can do it this way.